# Creating a flying animation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-animation

I'd like to have a kind of "Fly In" PowerPoint like animation done in Xcode.

The view will fly-in from a given direction (up,down, left, right) stop at the center of the screen for a given amount of time and then continue flying in the same direction until it goes out of screen

I've tried playing with the different animation options, but all act like:

```
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
```

So I'm doing something wrong?

```
UIViewAnimationOptions animationOption[] = {
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
};

self.frame = p_newFrame;
int idx = arc4random() % 8;
[UIView animateWithDuration:p_duration delay:0.8 options:animationOption[idx] animations:^{
      self.alpha = 1.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

Can anyone help with code example?

Comment: Have you looked at the view controller transition API?

Comment: @Aaron I've googled `view controller transition API`, it seems it starts from ios 7 my application support 6 and above

Comment: Do you want to just animate the adding of a subview (and itself having subviews) having it fly in and then off-screen? Or do you want to animate the transition between view controllers (and if so, do these view controllers' views take up the whole screen or not)? Are these screens you're transitioning to scenes in your storyboard or something you're going to create programmatically? Is the sequence and animation to be determined up front? A little more context would be helpful.

Comment: @Rob, Thank you for your feedback, it's a small rectangle subview added programmatically, it shows a message, I wish to animate the way it's added to the main view (fly in/ on top of the main view) stops at center, and animate the exit (fly out in the same direction as before until it's frame position is not on screen)

Answer (score 3):

Lots of ways to accomplish this, but one easy technique is to add a subview, setting the initial `frame` such that it's initially off-screen. Then, animate the changing of the `frame` so it's within the visible screen. Then, in the completion block, have another animation (this one with a delay) to animate it flying off the other direction. E.g.

```
CGRect frameVisible = self.view.bounds;                                // Or use `CGRectMake` to specify something smaller than the whole screen
CGRect frameRight = frameVisible;
frameRight.origin.x += self.view.frame.size.width;
CGRect frameLeft = frameVisible;
frameLeft.origin.x -= self.view.frame.size.width;

UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frameRight];           // add if off screen to right

// just doing this so I can see it; you'd presumably add all sorts of subviews
// (labels, images, whatever)

subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];                    // I'm just going to make it gray, so I can see it

[self.view addSubview:subview];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^{
    subview.frame = frameVisible;                                      // animate it on screen
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:3.0 options:0 animations:^{  // wait 3 sec, then ...
        subview.frame = frameLeft;                                     // ... animate it off screen to left
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];                                 // when all done, remove it from screen
    }];
}];
```

Just adjust the various `CGRect` values you'll use for the `frame` property to control where it starts, where it stops on screen, and where it flies off to.